# Java for loop is always returning true

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the below code. Here the result is always pass where as I have 2 failed scenarios.

```
List<WebElement> webElementslist = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
for (WebElement webElementlist : webElementslist)
{
    // System.out.println("Start Application"+webElementlist.getText());
    for (int i = 2; i <= DisText.getRowCount("TRAText"); i++)
    {
        // System.out.println("Start Excel"+DisText.getCellData("TRAText", "Description", i));
        if (webElementlist.getText().equals(DisText.getCellData("TRAText", "Description", i)))
        {
            tflag = true;
        }
    }
    if (tflag)
        extent.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Display Text", "Its Pass");
    // Reporter.log("Pass");
    else
        extent.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Display Text", "Its Fail");
}
```

Comment: what is the default value of tflag

Comment: try to re-intialize the tflag to false before the second loop starts.

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample code how it should be in my opinion.

```
 for (WebElement webElementlist : webElementslist)
{
tflag = false;

for (int i = 2; i <= DisText.getRowCount("TRAText"); i++)
{
    // System.out.println("Start Excel"+DisText.getCellData("TRAText", "Description", i));
    if (webElementlist.getText().equals(DisText.getCellData("TRAText", "Description", i)))
    {
        tflag = true;
    }
}
if (tflag)
    extent.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Display Text", "Its Pass");
// Reporter.log("Pass");
else
    extent.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Display Text", "Its Fail");
}
```

Edit: I changed the code- thanks @Jeff C for clarification.

Comment: The inner loop will only execute once because you break on if true AND if false

Answer (score 0):

```
for (WebElement webElementlist : webElementslist)
{
    tflag = false;// initialize..it will be true only if condition is true
    for (int i = 2; i <= DisText.getRowCount("TRAText"); i++)
    {
        // System.out.println("Start Excel"+DisText.getCellData("TRAText", "Description", i));
        if (webElementlist.getText().equals(DisText.getCellData("TRAText", "Description", i)))
        {
            tflag = true;
        }
    }
    if (tflag)
        extent.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Display Text", "Its Pass");
    // Reporter.log("Pass");
    else
        extent.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Display Text", "Its Fail");
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code only answers. Spend a minute and tell the OP and future readers what you added or changed and why so they can not only have the code but learn something too.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a couple of things. First, you need to set `tflag` to false before the inner loop because once you set it to true, it will never be set to false. Second, I think you would want to break out of the inner loop once you find a match. I have added the new statements in your code below with comments so you can see them.

```
List<WebElement> webElementslist = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
for (WebElement webElementlist : webElementslist)
{
    tflag = false; // need to reset tflag for each element
    for (int i = 2; i <= DisText.getRowCount("TRAText"); i++)
    {
        if (webElementlist.getText().equals(DisText.getCellData("TRAText", "Description", i)))
        {
            tflag = true;
            break; // break out of for loop when match is found... for each element
        }
    }
    if (tflag)
        extent.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Display Text", "Its Pass");
    else
        extent.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Display Text", "Its Fail");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is Sample Code

```
List<WebElement> webElementslist = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
        for (WebElement webElementlist : webElementslist) {
            //System.out.println("Start Application"+webElementlist.getText());
            for (int i = 2; i <= DisText.getRowCount("TRAText"); i++) {
                //System.out.println("Start Excel"+DisText.getCellData("TRAText", "Description", i));
                if (webElementlist.getText().equals(DisText.getCellData("TRAText", "Description", i))) {
                    tflag = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    tflag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (tflag)
                extent.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Display Text", "Its Pass");
                //Reporter.log("Pass");
            else
                extent.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Display Text", "Its Fail");
        }
```

Comment: @Shubham Jain....I havn't copied code. if you can see...i added break statement for logic to be correct.

Comment: The inner loop will only execute once because you break on if true AND if false.

Comment: Please don't post code only answers. Spend a minute and tell the OP and future readers what you added or changed and why so they can not only have the code but learn something too.